# How to apply changes without access to svn server

Tags: svn, deployment, production

We are using svn for development of a large web application, and we do periodic updates to production.  The production server does not have access to svn (for security reasons).

What is the best way to push the changes since the last production release for a new release?  We would like to avoid re-creating the whole site each time, since it is very large.

Comment: I don't understand how the problem of releasing to a production server is connected to the problem of version control. Can you elaborate?

Comment: To see if I understand. You do an SVN update on machine A and then you copy the entire site directory to production machine. You want to just copy the things that changed with this SVN update, thus avoiding copying the entire directory. Is that it?

Comment: If the production server was connected to the svn server, we would just go on the production server and do svn update.  But it's not connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well let me give a shot. You can parse the SVN update command output and generate copy instructions that only copy the files that were changed?

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch03s05.html

> Let's examine the output of svn update
>   a bit more. When the server sends
>   changes to your working copy, a letter
>   code is displayed next to each item to
>   let you know what actions Subversion
>   performed to bring your working copy
>   up-to-date:
>
> `U foo`
>
> File foo was Updated (received
>   changes from the server).
>
> `A foo`
>
> File or directory foo was Added
>   to your working copy.
>
> `D foo`
>
> File or directory foo was
>   Deleted from your working copy.
>
> `R foo`
>
> File or directory foo was
>   Replaced in your working copy; that
>   is, foo was deleted, and a new item
>   with the same name was added. While
>   they may have the same name, the
>   repository considers them to be
>   distinct objects with distinct
>   histories.
>
> `G foo`
>
> File foo received new changes
>   from the repository, but your local
>   copy of the file had your
>   modifications. Either the changes did
>   not intersect, or the changes were
>   exactly the same as your local
>   modifications, so Subversion has
>   successfully merGed the repository's
>   changes into the file without a
>   problem.
>
> `C foo`
>
> File foo received Conflicting
>   changes from the server. The changes
>   from the server directly overlap your
>   own changes to the file. No need to
>   panic, though. This overlap needs to
>   be resolved by a human (you); we
>   discuss this situation later in this
>   chapter.

Or if you prefer a semi-manual solution you can use a diff tool like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) or [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/) to sync both directories.

**EDIT:**

I don't think "svn update" will work exactly, but what I settled on was:

- svn **checkout** of the current (old) prod revision
- svn **switch** to the revision that is ready for prod (new)

I wrote a script to capture the output of the "switch".  It translates U and A operations to "adds" to a zip archive.  It translates D operations to delete commands to be executed on the production server.  On the production server, we just need to unzip the archive and run the delete commands.

Comment: How do I set up the working directory before doing the update?

Comment: just `cd` there and do `svn update`.

$ svn update
A  newdir/toggle.c
A  newdir/disclose.c
A  newdir/launch.c
D  newdir/README
Updated to revision 32.

Comment: It will have no updates, because it is the development directory!

Comment: Create a new folder that is just for this purpose.

Comment: I think I figured it out... not svn update... svn checkout of the current prod version, then svn switch to the version that is ready for prod

Comment: Yes. Do a `svn checkout` in a machine that has access to SVN. That is the directory that you will sync with the production server. After you do the first checkout you always do `svn update` from that point on.

Answer (score 0):

Do a checkout to a directory on your side of the glass wall, make it accessible from the production server.  Use some sort of diff/sync utility to synchronize the two, minus the _svn folders or any other files that would contaiminate the production environment.

Or use a zip (or other archive) of files with "changes since mm/dd/yyyy", and apply it to the prodution directory.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what utility to use?

Comment: @Joel Try `rsync` on unixoids or `robocopy` on Windows. Both can syncronize one directory to another, while transferring only the changed files.

Comment: Unison on unix is popular, I tried to get it working once... I think it's available for Windows too.  You could use either Unison or rsync within CYGWin, I think.

SecondCopy for Windows.  
You can use BeyondCompare on Windows, to do it manually (useful if you're not sure you know what you're doing). 
FileBoss on Windows.
There are lots of these things.